# Calculating town distance excluding the locations with time in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I have two tables

**Location:** Has Town name, locations latitude/longitude, and date the town was opened

```
|--------------|------------|------------|-------------------|
|    Towns     |  latitude  | longitude  |  establish_time   |
|--------------|------------|------------|-------------------|
|  Town_A      |  72.92629  | -12.89272  |    2021-07-21     |
|  Town_B      |  93.62789  | -83.10172  |    2021-08-21     |
|  Town_C      |  68.92612  | -67.17242  |    2021-09-21     |
|--------------|------------|------------|-------------------|
```

**Users:** Has user_id, user latitude/longitude, town they purchased movie tickets, time of purchase

```
|------------|------------|------------|--------------|-----------------|
|   user_id  |  latitude  | longitude  |    Towns     |  purchase_time  |
|------------|------------|------------|--------------|-----------------|
|    1       |  21.89027  | -53.03772  |   Town_A     |    2021-08-19   |
|    1       |  23.87847  | -41.78172  |   Town_C     |    2021-09-29   |
|    1       |  77.87092  | -96.39242  |   Town_A     |    2021-11-07   |
|    2       |  83.37847  | -62.78278  |   Town_B     |    2021-10-21   |
|    3       |  89.81924  | -80.73892  |   Town_B     |    2021-12-07   |
|    3       |  27.87282  | -18.39183  |   Town_A     |    2021-08-23   |
|------------|------------|------------|--------------|-----------------|
```

I'm trying to find the shortest distance from user location to the all other towns at the time of ticket purchase_time

Here is my SQL (Snowflake):

```
SELECT 
        u.*,
        seq4() as seq,
        l.town as nearest_town,
        haversine(u.latitude, u.longitude, l.latitude, l.longitude)
    FROM User AS u, location AS l
    QUALIFY row_number() OVER (PARTION BY u.seq ORDER BY haversine(u.latitude, u.longitude, l.latitude, l.longitude)) = 1
```

The result I'm getting is actually based on the user location as follows:

```
|------------|------------|------------|--------------|-----------------|
|   user_id  |  latitude  | longitude  |    Towns     | nearest_town    |
|------------|------------|------------|--------------|-----------------|
|    1       |  21.89027  | -53.03772  |   Town_C     |   Town_C        |
|    1       |  23.87847  | -41.78172  |   Town_C     |   Town_A        | 
|    1       |  77.87092  | -96.39242  |   Town_A     |   Town_B        | <--- This should be Town_A because Town_B was not present at the time of purchase
|    2       |  83.37847  | -62.78278  |   Town_B     |   Town_C        |
|    3       |  89.81924  | -80.73892  |   Town_B     |   Town_A        |
|    3       |  27.87282  | -18.39183  |   Town_A     |   Town_C        | <--- This should be Town_A because Town_B was not present at the time of purchase
|------------|------------|------------|--------------|-----------------|
```

The above query is resulting in nearest_town even when the town didn't exist at the time of purchase_time

**How can I exclude the un-opened towns during calculating the nearest_towns**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your implicit `CROSS JOIN` (implied by your comma delimited list of tables in your FROM clause) to an `INNER JOIN` where the `ON` condition is the date restriction you want to add.

Something like

```
FROM Users AS u
    INNER JOIN location AS l
        ON l.establish_time <= u.purchase_time
```

This says, in English "Only consider locations that were established before the purchase of this ticket when joining these two tables".